# Code First Entity Framework C#, Many to Many Mapping, Junction Table Created but list property not populated on object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Many Users can Send Many Message Requests to Many Other Users

USERS

Id

Name

Age

MESSAGE REQUESTS

Id

Message

FromUserID

ToUserID

`ICollection<User> RequestUsers`

I am trying to set up my class for this using code first.
I have managed to get code first and EF to create the junction table but this is no good as the MessageRequest junction table is only
used by the database. I am looking for a way to add it to part of the context so I can work with it in code.

I want to be able to get a list of all users that have had a message request sent to them based on the Message Request ID.

Even though code first created the junction table, when I debug the application and inspect RequestUsers property it is null and I want it
to be populated automatically to work with in code.

I have tried all kinds of mappings but can't get it to work.

Can someone please explain how to layout the two classes for code first in ER and how I can get the RequestUsers Property to be populated automatically 
with the list of related users?

Comment: Could you post the code that you have? Your entities in question, specifically.

Comment: This really needs the code for your entities and mappings.

Comment: You can use the [fluent code here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) or you can use [this method](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/03/12/avoid-many-to-many-mappings-in-orms/).

Answer (score 0):

Any time you're talking about EF classes, you should post the class definitions. It's nearly impossible to answer a question like this otherwise. That said, I can take a guess that you neglected to add the `virtual` keyword to your collection, i.e.:

```
public virtual ICollection<User> RequestUsers { get; set; }
```

Without `virtual` EF will not load the relationship.